# Comparing QByteArrays

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a file editor in Qt C++.
I noticed that when I save the source file with notepad on Windows it substitutes 0x0D + 0x0A for every new line (ANSI encoding default).

If I get the data from a QTextEdit and convert that to a QByteArray it substitutes line endings with 0x0A.

Now my main problem is that I don't know how to either filter out these line endings or make it so that QFile reads files different.

I just want a way of comparing whether there are changes that need to be saved.
The code is below:

```
bool QFileTab::needSave()
{
    QFile file1 ( this->filePath );
    file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QByteArray data1 ( file1.readAll() );
    QByteArray data2 ( this->body.toPlainText().toLocal8Bit() );

    file1.close();
    return !IOHandler::compare(data1, data2);
}

void IOHandler::read(QFileTab *tab)
{
    QFile temp (tab->filePath);
    if(temp.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QString data(temp.readAll());
        tab->data = data;
        temp.close();

    } else tab->data = QString("The file could not be read.");

    tab->doUpdate();
}

bool IOHandler::compare(QByteArray data1, QByteArray data2)
{
    return data1 == data2;
}
```

I want to be able to read, compare and write to files on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Windows uses `"\r\n"` (carriage-return and newline) for newlines, which is why it's important to open text files in text mode as then the translation between single newline ('\n') to the Windows newline should be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks, now it appears to be working and it was really that simple.